# Arduino: I need to turn off the RGB cycle (Blue, Red, Green) immediately but it finish the cycle always

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-c++

I am learning arduino and I am doing an assignment, my arduino needs to turn off the lights when I push the second button completely but when push it, it always finish the cycle (example: if I press it during showing red, it shows green and after it turns off) but I need to stop it immediately. Please help :c
I tried to use boolean variables, even put in the code and in the function to turn off the RGB but it always finish the cycle, I know the easiest way is to add an if after each color but that is not efficient

````
int redLed=9;
int greenLed=8;
int blueLed=7;
int count= 3;
int button1= 3;
int button2= 2;
boolean stopCycle=false;
int newButton1;
int newButton2;
void setup() {
  pinMode(redLed, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(blueLed, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(greenLed, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(button1, INPUT);
  pinMode(button2, INPUT);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(button1), repetition, CHANGE);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(button2), turnOff, CHANGE);
}

void loop() {
  if (stopCycle) {
    digitalWrite(redLed, LOW);
    digitalWrite(blueLed, LOW);
    digitalWrite(greenLed, LOW);
    return; // Detener el ciclo inmediatamente
  }
  if(stopCycle==false){
  digitalWrite(blueLed, HIGH);
  delay(500);
  digitalWrite(blueLed, LOW);
  delay(10);
  digitalWrite(redLed, HIGH);
  delay(500);
  digitalWrite(redLed, LOW);
  delay(10);
  digitalWrite(greenLed, HIGH);
  delay(500);
  digitalWrite(greenLed, LOW);
  delay(10);
}
}
void repetition() {
  stopCycle = false;
}

void turnOff() {
  stopCycle = true;
      digitalWrite(redLed, LOW);
    digitalWrite(blueLed, LOW);
    digitalWrite(greenLed, LOW);
    return; // Detener el ciclo inmediatamente```
````

Answer (score 0):

So after 4 hours I was able to fix it to anyone who may interest lol

```cpp
int redLed=9;
int greenLed=8;
int blueLed=7;
int count= 3;
int button1= 3;
int button2= 2;
boolean stopCycle=false;
int switchLed=1;
int turnOffLed=0;

void setup() {
  pinMode(redLed, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(blueLed, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(greenLed, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(button1, INPUT);
  pinMode(button2, INPUT);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(button1), repetition, CHANGE);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(button2), turnOff, CHANGE);
}

void loop() {
  if(stopCycle==false){
    digitalWrite(blueLed, switchLed);
    delay(500);
    digitalWrite(blueLed, turnOffLed);
    delay(10);
    digitalWrite(redLed, switchLed);
    delay(500);
    digitalWrite(redLed, turnOffLed);
    delay(10);
    digitalWrite(greenLed, switchLed);
    delay(500);
    digitalWrite(greenLed, turnOffLed);
    delay(10);
  }
}

void repetition() {
  stopCycle = false;
  switchLed=1;
}

void turnOff() {
  switchLed=0;
}
```